# How to add percentage values to strata in alluvial plot with ggalluvial?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I'm looking for the most convenient way for adding rounded percentage labels to strata of an alluvial plot.
There are 50 cases in the following example. Independently of stages 1 or 2, each case belongs to one group of A, B or C. I'd like to display the relative group affiliation during each stage.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggalluvial)

df <- data.frame('id' = rep(1:50,2),
                     'stage' = c(rep(1,50), rep(2,50)),
                     'group' = sample(c('A','B','C'), 100, replace = TRUE))

ggplot(df,
       aes(x = stage, stratum = group, alluvium = id, fill = group)) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(.1, .1)) +
  geom_flow() +
  geom_stratum(alpha = .5)
```

[image]

Is there a way to add rounded percentage labels (including "%") to the strata (bar segments) without calculating a percentage column in the initial data frame? If I'm not completely mistaken, geom_text doesn't work the same way here as in geom_bar().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard ggplot2 solution to this question is to use "calculated aesthetics". These are aesthetic specifications that come not from the data passed to `ggplot()` but from the output of the statistical transformation (the `stat_*()`), which is used to render the graphical elements (the `geom_*()`). The columns of this output (which are rarely seen by the user) are called "computed variables". [The documentation on this topic](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/stat.html) is limited and a bit out of date, using `stat()` instead of `after_stat()` to call them. Since ggalluvial did not support computed variables, the answer from @bencekd was correct at the time.

As of today, v0.12.0 is on CRAN with support and documentation for computed variables. In particular, three computed variables are available that correspond to variables with the same names used by `stat_bin()` or `stat_count()`: `n`, `count` (a weighted version of `n`), and `prop` (a within-axis proportion calculated from `count`). It looks like you'd want to use `prop`, as illustrated below:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(ggalluvial)

df <- data.frame('id' = rep(1:50,2),
                 'stage' = c(rep(1,50), rep(2,50)),
                 'group' = sample(c('A','B','C'), 100, replace = TRUE))

ggplot(df,
       aes(x = stage, stratum = group, alluvium = id, fill = group)) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(.1, .1)) +
  geom_flow() +
  geom_stratum(alpha = .5) +
  geom_text(stat = "stratum",
            aes(label = percent(after_stat(prop), accuracy = .1)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Cory. Any hint on how to print the amount of elements in the flows, too?

Comment: @DavideChicco.it have a look at [this vignette](http://corybrunson.github.io/ggalluvial/articles/order-rectangles.html), which showcases computed variables and labels for all graphical objects. Is your question answered there?

Comment: Thanks! That resource is useful but does not solve my issue. If I use `+ geom_text(stat = "flow", aes(label = after_stat(count)))` all the quantities of the blocks are printed, but they overlap between each other and the plot becomes a mess ultimately. Would it be possible to print the quantities in the flows between the blocks? Thanks

Comment: @DavideChicco.it you could try doing your own calculation on the calculated variables; but the core problem is that each flow is defined by _two_ (not one, as usual) rows of the output of `StatFlow`, so it would take some creative hacking to locate text at the centroid of each flow. An alternative is to adjust it slightly using, e.g., `hjust = after_stat(flow) == "to"`, as in the vignette. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't think you can do it without calculating the percentage column in the initial data frame yet. But that can be done easily and also gives more flexibility with the labeling:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggalluvial)

df <- data.frame('id' = rep(1:50,2),
                     'stage' = c(rep(1,50), rep(2,50)),
                     'group' = sample(c('A','B','C'), 100, replace = TRUE))

# the list needs to be reversed, as stratums are displayed reversed in the alluvial by default

stratum_list <- df %>% 
  group_by(stage, group) %>% 
  summarize(s = n()) %>%
  group_by(stage) %>%
  mutate(s = percent(s/sum(s), accuracy=0.1)) %>%
  arrange(stage, -as.numeric(group)) %>% 
  .$s

ggplot(df,
       aes(x = stage, stratum = group, alluvium = id, fill = group)) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(.1, .1)) +
  geom_flow() +
  geom_stratum(alpha = .5) + 
  geom_text(stat = "stratum", label=stratum_list)
```

[image]

**UPDATE [13/04/2020]**

Added `stratum_list` reversion as [Yonghao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5427825/yonghao) suggested